# Apply ssl on a pm2 api with apache on linux

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, centos7, pm2

I got a dedicated server for a project(angular/nodejs). I already configured centos web panel and through this, my domain with let's encrypt ssl, frontend and backend api and everything is up and running so far.

The backend api is running through jenkins/pm2 and it's up on my ip:port3333 but I need it to be ssl, so for example, I would need it to be https://api.example.com:3333 otherwise I'm getting this error on my project: `This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

If I try https://example.com:3333 or https://subdomain.example.com:3333 i get an ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR which i guess it's normal since centos web panel seems to apply only to the main domain.

So, how can I point a domain or subdomain to the service port 3333 and apply an ssl to it? Or if I can't, how should I proceed to get the service running with ssl? Do i really need this config serverside or is it a matter of the app.

Any idea on how to proceed? Not sure what config should I share.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was caused by a missconfiguration on my reverse proxy on apache to a custom port.

Comment: Care to elaborate?